# EmberJS: Where to place a function for computed properties?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

For some of my models I’d like to use the same computed property. But instead of writing the same function in every single model like this:

```
imageURL: function(){
  var path = '/images/',
      ext = ".jpg";
  return path + this.get('shortID') + ext;
}.property('shortID')
```

I would like to to something like this

```
imageURL: function(){
  return makeImageURL(this.get('shortID'));
}.property('shortID')
```

And have this makeImageURL function somewhere:

```
makeImageURL = function(shortID) {
  var path = '/images/',
    ext = ".jpg";
  return path + shortID + ext;
}
```

But where? BTW I am using Ember-CLI.

Comment: If a helper works for you that's fine, but you could also write your own computed property definition, it's not that hard and turns out to be quite useful. Consult the relevant section in the ember docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given any thought to making `imageURL` a computed property inside a component? This way you can  reuse the component whenever you need to.

Another option would be to create an ember handlebars helper that computes `imageURL` based on a parameter that is passed to it. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/)

Comment: Solved it with the handlebars helper. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `ember-cli` you run `ember g util image` in the terminal, which will create a new file in `app/utils/image`, there you can place your utility functions for images like so:

```
export default {
  makeImageURL: function(shortID) {
    var path = '/images/',
      ext = ".jpg";
    return path + shortID + ext;
  }
};
```

and you can use it in your model with

```
import { makeImageURL } from 'utils/image';
```

Comment: This is pretty nice, too. I will use it on another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use [Mixins](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html)

```
// app/mixins/image.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    imageURL: function(){
       var path = '/images/',
       ext = ".jpg";
       return path + this.get('shortID') + ext;
    }.property('shortID')
});
```

use it in some model like

```
// app/models/some-model.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ImageUrl from '../mixins/image';

export default DS.Model.extend(ImageUrl, {
    dummy: DS.attr('string')
});
```